# 1.8.9 Tesfor specific player at a specific xyz

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make this command work:

```
/testfor mastermc123 [x=506,y=4,z=-879,r=1]
```

But I get this error:

`Data tag parsing failed: Ivalid tag encountered expected { as first char`

So, I tried:

`/testfor mastermc123 {x=506,y=4,z=-879,r=1}`

But I get this error:

```
Data tag parsing failed: unable too locate name/value separator for string x=506,y=4,z=-879,r=1
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

Selector arguments can only be used with a selector (`@p`, `@a`, `@r`, or `@e`). There must also be no space between the selector and the selector arguments:

```
/testfor @a[x=506,y=4,z=-879,r=1]
```

If you want to include a name, you can use the `name=` selector argument:

```
/testfor @a[x=506,y=4,z=-879,r=1,name=mastermc123]
```